What medal was Olson awarded in the Mexican-American War?
In The Dead Don't Hurt, Holger Olson is a veteran of the Mexican-American War, citing his time as a soldier as the main reason he feels obligated to enlist in the American Civil War. Before he leaves to enlist, he takes the medal he earned from his previous service and pins it to his chest (the screenshot is from the trailer, but it is shown more prominently in the full film).

What is the medal that he earned for his time spent in the Mexican-American War?

I don't think there were any official medals awarded by either the US or the Mexican government during the Mexican American war.  The Purple Heart was awared  3 times in the Revolution, and not again until 1932, while the Medal of Honor was not arwarded until the Civil War.  So there were no US medals for the Mexican War.


What is the medal that he earned for his time spent in the Mexican-American War?

It's not.
It seems to be the Order Of The Dannebrog a Danish medal

The Order of the Dannebrog (Danish: Dannebrogordenen)[3] is a Danish order of chivalry instituted in 1671 by Christian V. Until 1808, membership in the Order was limited to fifty members of noble or royal rank,[4] who formed a single class known as White Knights to distinguish them from the Blue Knights who were members of the Order of the Elephant.[5] In 1808, the Order was reformed and divided into four classes. The statute of the Order was amended in 1951 by a Royal Ordinance so that both men and women could be members of the Order. Today, the Order of the Dannebrog is a means of honouring and rewarding the faithful servants of the modern Danish state for meritorious civil or military service, for a particular contribution to the arts, sciences or business life, or for working for Danish interests.

You can see the various grades/ranks of medal HERE

Oh wow, I should have picked up on that detail, that's super cool.
